# selecting data based on common id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am designing a peer to peer video system, which has two tables

video(creater_id, video_name, duration,viewer_id)

viewer_or_host(host_id,viewer_name,location)

host_id and viewer_id , a viewer can be a host as well.

I am trying to form an sql where I need to find who viewed the content from whom.

John watched content X created by Jake

I tried

```
select B.viewer_name,A.video_name from video A join viewer_or_host B 
on a.viewer_id = b.host_id
```

but this will not help me to get the host name like Jake.

EDIT

Sample data

Video

```
1, full.mpg, 68,2
2, small.mpg, 30,1
```

Viewer_or_host

```
2,Jake,London
1,John,Mountain View
```

Comment: How is this different from your earlier question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68396786/circular-dependency-on-joining-table

Comment: Why shouldn't I just close this as a duplicate again?

Comment: delete the other one and added sample data

Comment: Why did you delete the other one and just post the same question again? I gave you a link to another question that shows how to solve it. Why haven't you used that?

Comment: Join with `viewer_or_host` twice. Once on `creator_id = host_id`, the other time on `viewer_id = host_id`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, your solution works.

Comment: You should split up the `videos` table, since the same video can be viewed by multiple people. Take the `viewer_id` column out, and create another `video_viewer` table that contains `video_id, viewer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need more than two tables. I recommend separating the "viewer_or_host" table into two tables, one for hosts and one for viewers.

Each table should have their own primary key, host_id for the host table, and viewer_id for the viewer table. Then it will link properly to your video table. Video table would need the foreign keys host_id and viewer_id.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No he doesn't. Just join the one table twice, joining on different colums in the `video` table.

Comment: The `viewer_or_host` table is essentially just a `person` table, mapping an ID to a name and location.